# How to send events from server to client in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have a collection of POCOs (not entities) on my server that I'd like to synchronize with a mirrored list in the Silverlight client.  I'd like to send events from the server to the client whenever the list changes.

I can see how I could use RIA Services to do this if I were using Entities, but my objects are just regular objects.

What methods can I use to send events from server to client, for the purpose of keeping a list of objects synchronized, when the objects are not entities?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RIA Services can actually transfer objects that aren't entities from an Entity Framework model.  These are generally referred to as presentation model objects.  You can find some more information about doing so here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707347(v=vs.91).aspx.

However, it seems to me that you actually want to push data to the client from the server, rather than have the client pull the data from the server.  RIA Services won't help you here.  So instead, you are better off taking a look at duplex communication using WCF and the Net.Tcp binding.  This series of articles by Gil Cleeren discusses this in more detail: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/The-duplex-story-looking-at-duplex-communication-in-Silverlight-4-Part-1.aspx.

Hope this helps...

Chris Anderson